# Promql for metrics which have not reported in x minutes

Tags: promql

I have a watch dog application which send metrics every 10 mins to the centralised prometheus. One metric with the name watchdog and it will have multiple timeseries one for each cluster per 10 mins. I want to write an alert query which will trigger an alert if for any prometheus the metrics is not updated/reported for 20 mins(2 cycles).

I tried few options but none of the promql is giving me the correct result. Can someone please help in writing the promql.

watchdog metric is a gauge with a value 1 and has labels like cluster_id, cluster_profile, cluster_region etc.

Comment: When you say "send[s] every 10 minutes" what do you mean exactly? Is there remote_write involved? Or is your scrape_interval simply set to 10m for those targets? And if latter, how does metric `up` looks for your targets?

Comment: It is writing to the centralised system using remote write. Thanks for your response.